# How to remove excess whitespaces in entire python dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the pythonic way of removing all excess whitespaces in a dateframe(all the columns). I know the method **.str.strip()** can be used for single column or for each column. The dataframe as many columns as such I would like to apply the method on the entire dataframe.
The whitespaces occur at different points, beginning of text, in between and at the end. Attached is view of what the dataframe looks like before and after removing the spaces. The dataframe below is the expected result.

[image]

I have searched and most related questions I came across  were for a single column.

## Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['  James Brown  ', '10', 'USA'], ['   James   Bond', '15', 'UK'], ['Jimbo Bosco  ', '14', 'Unknown']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Country'])
´´´
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `apply`:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: " ".join(x.split()) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Comment: I added a sample data. I want to remove the excess spaces in the beginning, in between and at end. Also return the data back as a dataframe

Comment: Edited my answer to include spaces in between. This should return data as a dataframe too. Btw, you can enhance your question even more by adding an expected data sample.

Comment: I attached an image showing the dataframe before and after. The dataframe below is the expected result. Your code works now but returns a list instead of each cell.

Comment: I see, updated my answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Can you just explain the use of "isinstance". Is it to ignore cells that are not string?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, without that the function would fail if any of the data was for example integers or floats, because it's doing string operations.

Comment: Okay thanks. Just wanted to be sure. I had converted the whole dataframe to string initially with "df.applymap(str)". It is not in the sample dataframe.
Learnt a few things from your code.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to do a combination of:

- `regex` to remove duplicate spaces (e.g "   James   Bond" to " James Bond")
- `str.strip` to remove leading/trailing spaces (e.g " James Bond" to "James Bond").

You could do this one of two ways:

### 1. On the whole DataFrame:

```py
df = df.replace("\s+", " ", regex=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

### 2. On each column individually:

```py
for col in ["Name", "Country"]:
    df[col] = df[col].replace("\s+", " ", regex=True).str.strip()
```

Comment: I will give the first solution s try. Looks similar to the solution accepted

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, seems shorter and cleaner:

```py
df[col] = df[col].str.replace(' ','')
```

You can use it to replace any string items in the column values.

Comment: there's a few problems with your answer. using `.str.replace(' ','')` will replace all spaces, not just leading or trailing spaces – so `"  James   Brown"` would become `"JamesBrown"` which is definitely not the desired outcome – `.str.strip()` seems appropriate, and the person asking the question already knows this. also the question specifically asks about the most pythonic way to apply this to as many columns as needed – if we use your answer and apply it to every column, it may have the unintended consequence of converting numeric columns (such as `Age`) to a string

Comment: The OP has clearly mentioned that he knows how to do this for a column; but he wants to do for entire dataframe as he has lots of columns.